# how to force oledbdatareader to ignore first column of database in c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, dbf, oledbconnection, oledbdataadapter

I'm trying to develop a C# application by reading a file from old database (.DBF) using OleDbConnection, OleDbDataAdapter, DataSet and DataGridView. So far, all the help that I got from this website was extremely helpful, until I got into this problem.

This is the
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQxHz.jpg) content of the database. The COLORS field has 293 characters.

When I type in the code and load the result into the datagridview,
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kneVF.jpg) was what came out. 
It splits into 244 characters in [COLORS] and 49 characters in [DATADIR], while the rest of column remain empty.

Does OLEDB method automatically split the characters and parse it into the next column?

I only want the result from Column [CURGEN]. I don't want the result from Column [COLORS]. Any suggestion or advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: can you show an example what should be the output u need and what is the o/p currently coming

Comment: @ Sanchu, I would like the output to be like this

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=24981764193860270951

thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

When you build your query you can do

```
select mycolumn from mytable
```

Comment: I did that too. It return empty result. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Here is my code......
string strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\folder;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;";
string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM SYSTEM" + ".DBF";
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(strConnection);
connection.Open();

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, connection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
datagridview1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

Thanks for answering....

Comment: if it helps, i can send a sample of database file via email. Thanks

Comment: Yes give me your file, via a share like Dropbox or other. I dont can give my mail here and i dont no if you can directly send me this file by stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Before, have you the last driver? `https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14839`

Comment: @ Esperento57, I'm using tinyupload. Here's the link:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05595236157871962965

Thanks

Comment: @ Esperento57, I tried using using the microsoft driver that you posted.
The result still the same as what I posted before, like this [http://i.stack.imgur.com/kneVF.jpg]

I changed the provider to VFPOLEDB.1 like this
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\\;");

Thanks

Comment: @rmarrmar in the sample .dbf there is nothing for the column curgen

Comment: @sanchu in sample.dbf there are values in all column. But, when I read/load using c# application, all columns are empty except column 1 & 2

Comment: @rmarrmar i opened your sample.dbf using excel in that except first two columns all columns have null values

Comment: @sanchu.
Yes, you are correct. I tried to open using Excel program, and it was all empty except the first column.
BUT, when I opened using DBF Viewer 2000, there are data in all columns.

Comment: Only 2 columns with data in your file, same with DBF Viewer 2000

Comment: @ Esperento57, are you sure about that? could you post the picture so that I can see the content? This is picture from my DBF Viewer 2000 2.02 program (http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=72515922569184593242)

Comment: @ Esperento57, @Sanchu
I think that maybe it is the DBF itself that has problems.
I'll try to resolve it by myself perhaps by creating new DBF database and copy paste the data and see how it goes.

Thank you for the time and effort that you guys have contributed for this problem.

Comment: @rmarrmar, for future, edit your original question with such things as table structures, sample code formatted with the curly braces icon in the editor header area and just short comments back to users like... updated original post with more details.  This prevents trying to read code in comments and such.  Also, read Help -> Tour for other site etiquette.  Welcome to S/O

Comment: @DRapp, This is my first time using S/O. I'll keep it in mind. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

like you want :)        [image dbf viewer 2000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESXLD.png)

Comment: Yes :) That's exactly what happened to me.....It splits into 2 columns.